# PHP: preg_match regex not finding correct strings

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match_all('/[\s]{1}(AA|BB|CC)+[\s]{1}/',' AA BB ',$matches);
```

result is `AA`, but I need `AA` and `BB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[\s]{1}` sequences* you're using to match whitespace overlap between the matches. The trailing space after `"AA "` is the same space as the one before `" BB"`. Any one character can only be matched a single time, so after the scan finds `" AA "` it only searches the remaining `"BB "` string for a match, and fails to find one.

Try the word boundary escape sequence `\b` instead. This matches the beginnings and ends of words but does not actually consume any characters, so it can match multiple times:

```
preg_match_all('/\b(AA|BB|CC)+\b/', 'AA BB', $matches);
```

Using `\b` has the bonus effect of not requiring the extra spaces you had surrounding your string. You can just pass in `'AA BB'` instead of `' AA BB '` if you wish.

<sup>* By the way, `[\s]{1}` is the same thing as `[\s]`, which is the same as a simple `\s`. No need for the square or curly brackets.</sup>

Comment: A word boundary will also match (e.g.) `AA;BB;CC`, which might be false positives.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to match the same space twice. Using a look ahead (?=\s) should help:

```
preg_match_all('/\s(AA|BB|CC)(?=\s)/',' AA BB CC BB AA ',$matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a positive look-behind:

`/(?<=\s)(AA|BB|CC)+\s/`

---

**Resources :**

- [regular-expressions.info - lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind)